# Error in execution of parallel partition on pre built table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE sf1 DATAFILE 'sf1.dbf' SIZE 40M ONLINE;
Tablespace created.

SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE sf2 DATAFILE 'sf2.dbf' SIZE 40M ONLINE;
Tablespace created.

SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE sf3 DATAFILE 'sf3.dbf' SIZE 40M ONLINE;
Tablespace created


SQL>  CREATE TABLE part_sales_tab_mv(time_id, cust_id, sum_dollar_sales, sum_unit_sale)
      2       PARALLEL PARTITION BY RANGE (time_id)
      3          (PARTITION month1
      4          VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('31-12-1998', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
      5          PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 99
      6          STORAGE (INITIAL 64k NEXT 16k PCTINCREASE 0)
      7          TABLESPACE sf1,
      8          PARTITION month2
      9          VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('31-12-1999', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
     10        PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 99
     11        STORAGE (INITIAL 64k NEXT 16k PCTINCREASE 0)
     12        TABLESPACE sf2,
     13        PARTITION month3
     14        VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('31-12-2000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
     15       PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 99
     16       STORAGE (INITIAL 64k NEXT 16k PCTINCREASE 0)
     17       TABLESPACE sf3)  AS
     18       SELECT s.time_id, s.cust_id, SUM(s.amount_sold) AS sum_dollar_sales
     19       SUM(s.quantity_sold) AS sum_unit_sales
     20       FROM sales s GROUP BY s.time_id, s.cust_id;
     CREATE TABLE part_sales_tab_mv(time_id, cust_id, sum_dollar_sales, sum_unit_
    sale)
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P000
>   ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition

I am executing this query on sales table of sh schema on oracle 10g. plz help me to resolve the error.The question for query is as follows:

Partition a prebuilt table part_sales_tab_mv as directed:

1. Create a table part_sales_tab_mv having partitions over three months
2. Register the materialized view to use the prebuilt table. This materialized view must be eligible for query rewrite

Comment: Your partitions are over three years, not three months; what date range do you have in your selected data? Something seems to be from the last day of 2000 (since 31/12/2000 is not less than your month3 partition range) or later.

Comment: date range from jan1998 to dec2001

Comment: OK, so any date in 2001 won't fit into any of your three partitions. My reading of the requirement is that you want interval range partition where the interval size is three months - so each partition has three months of data. Not three partitions. (My reading of the first part anyway; no idea what the second part is supposed to be doing...)

Comment: i think i need four partitions each having 3month interval

Comment: You could have four partitions *per year* of three months each, so 16 partitions in all, as your data spans four years. If you don't want to use interval partitioning. Pay attention to the boundaries though. (Not sure why you're creating a separate tablespace per partition... was that a requirement too?)

Comment: yes creating tablespace was also part of question...i forgot to include

Comment: Also check that time_id is not nullable (or is never null) on your input dataset - wouldn't be the first time I've thought it would be nice of Oracle to give a different error message for that...

Answer (score 1):

You are creating three partitions:

- `month1` includes any dates up to 1998-12-30 23:59:59
- `month2` includes any dates between 1998-12-31 00:00:00 and 1999-12-30 23:59:59
- `month3` includes any dates between 1999-12-31 00:00:00 and 2000-12-30 23:59:59

You said in a comment that you have data from January 1998 to December 2001. That spans four years, and your have three year-based partitions (almost, since your boundaries are off by a day); so there is nowhere for the data from 2001, or indeed from 2000-12-31, to go. That is what the error is telling you.

It looks from the first requirement that you want an interval range partitioned table where each partition covers three months; not three partitions, which would each have to cover 16 months to fit all your data in. Or 16 fixed partitions of three months each - an interval range would be more flexible later, but your tutor might be expecting fixed partitions.